# gnuplot animation 2D vector fields

Tags: animation, vector, gnuplot, gif, animated-gif

I'm trying to animate 2D vector with gnuplot. I want to show one line i.e, one vector at a time.

My Data Structure is as follows: They x,y,u,v

```
2.24448 0.270645    1.00    1.00
3.24448 0.270645    0.500   1.20
```

I'm able to create a static plot sing following command:

```
plot "datam.dat" using 1:2:3:4 with vectors filled head lw 3
```

Here is the output:
[image]

**Here is my question:** I would like to animate and show one row (i.e,) one **vector at a time**, how to accomplish this in GNU plot using GIF?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Animated GIFs are created with `set terminal gif animate`. Check `help gif` for details.
Below is a simple example (tested with gnuplot 5.2). You have to make a new plot for each frame. So, put your plot command into a `do for`-loop. With `every ::i::i` you are plotting only the `i`th line (check `help every`). If you don't know the total number of lines of your datafile, do `stats "YourFile.dat"` and the variable `STATS_records` will tell you this number.

**Code:**

```
### animated graph with vectors
reset session

set term gif size 300,300 animate delay 12 loop 0 optimize
set output "AnimateVectors.gif"

# create some dummy data
set angle degrees
N = 60
set samples N
set table $Data
    plot [0:360] '+' u (cos($1)):(sin($1)):(sin($1)):(cos($1)) w table
unset table

set xrange[-2.5:2.5]
set yrange[-2.5:2.5]
do for [i=0:N-1] {
    plot $Data u 1:2:3:4 every ::i::i w vectors lw 2 lc rgb "red" notitle
}
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

This would be the non-animated version, e.g. in a `wxt`-terminal.

**Code:**

```
### non-animated graph with vectors
reset session
set term wxt size 400,400

# create some dummy data
set angle degrees
N = 60
set samples N
set table $Data
    plot [0:360] '+' u (cos($1)):(sin($1)):(sin($1)):(cos($1)) w table
unset table

set xrange[-2.5:2.5]
set yrange[-2.5:2.5]
plot $Data u 1:2:3:4 w vectors lw 1.5 lc rgb "red" notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition2:**

Do you maybe mean something like this? A "semi"-animated arrow? By the way, as you can see the arrow look quite different in `gif` and `wxt` terminal.

**Code:**

```
### "semi"-animated graph with vectors
reset session
set term gif size 300,300 animate delay 12 loop 0 optimize
set output "AnimateVectorsSemi.gif"

# create some dummy data
set angle degrees
N = 60
set samples N
set table $Data
    plot [0:360] '+' u (cos($1)):(sin($1)):(sin($1)):(cos($1)) w table
unset table

set xrange[-2.5:2.5]
set yrange[-2.5:2.5]

do for [i=0:N-1] {
    plot $Data u 1:2:3:4 every ::0::i w vectors lw 1.5 lc rgb "red" notitle
}
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @theozh. I has a question, what if I want the vector to appear and stay?

Comment: well, what should be animated then?