# How do I animate an arrow using gnuplot?

Tags: c++, object, animation, gnuplot

I have the data from a double_pendulum.cpp C++ file, integrated with Runge-Kutta.
I used gnuplot to anmate the two bobs, but since there is no rod between them you can't full appreciate the pendulum nature of the animation.

So, how do I draw the rods?
I have the x and y positions of the two bobs. I use a do for loop to animate them. In this, how do I tell gnuplot to draw a line from, say, 0,2 (the pivot) to x1, y1 and from x1, y1 to x2, y2?

This is the .gp script for the animation.

```
    do for [i=1:10000:4] {
    
    title = sprintf ("t = %5.2f", i*0.01)
    set title title font ",18"
    tail = ((i - 25) < 0 ? 1 : i-24)
    
    plot   "dp.dat" u 6:7 index 0 every ::i::i linestyle 2, \              #second bob
           "dp.dat" u 6:7 index 0 every ::tail::i with lines lc 'blue', \  #tail of second bob
           "dp.dat" u 4:5 index 0 every ::i::i linestyle 2                 #first bob
}
```

Comment: have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56945844/7295599

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gnuplot animation 2D vector fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942993/gnuplot-animation-2d-vector-fields)